# JavaFX 8 - style ListCell but not any ListCells inside of the cells

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8

I have the following scenario (Screenshot from Scenic View):

[image: Screenshot from Scenic View]

If I do this, both of them will get styled:

```css
.list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(214, 236, 246);
}
```

or

```css
.list-view .list-cell:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgb(214, 236, 246);
}
```

A major problem is that the two highlighted `ListCell` elements both share the exact same classes and pseudo-classes when highlighted.

The problem is: I ONLY want to style the `ListCell` belonging to the `ListView` (the first one), not the one belonging to the `ComboBox`.

Comment: Just give a style class to the list cells you want to style, and use that style class as the selector. Post the code for your cell factory if you need more precise help.

Comment: @James_D That should be enough info. Thank you. Feel free to post this as an answer and I'll accept you.